# css file doesn't work on the server (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: html, css, file-upload, relative-path, mozilla

My program(web page) worked well on my computer without server.
So I try to upload my web page on the server.
And now only html files are working well. Css, json don't work.

console is as follows:

> GET https://(address)/online.json net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> GET https://(address)/css/online.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

folder structure is as follows (I use filemozilla and apache2):

```
/var/www/html/index.html
/var/www/html/online.json
/var/www/html/css/online.css
```

index.html is as follows:

```
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/online.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="online.json"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    body
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be a slash at the beginning of the row? Like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/online.css" type="text/css">
```